# Como faço um INNER JOIN com condição?

Tags: sql, inner-join

Tenho o seguinte SQL que me exibe apenas imóveis que tenham uma foto cadastrada, como especificado nas linhas:

```
INNER JOIN fotos
    ON imoveis.id = fotos.cod
```

Como fazer para exibir imóveis com ou sem fotos cadastradas?

**Segue o SQL completo**

```
SELECT
    imoveis.id, fotos.foto, imoveis.titulo, imoveis.descricao, imoveis.vvenda, imoveis.vtemporada, imoveis.vanual, imoveis.status, imoveis.cod
    FROM
    imoveis
    INNER JOIN fotos
    ON imoveis.id = fotos.cod
    INNER JOIN tipo
    ON imoveis.tipo = tipo.cod
    INNER JOIN bairros
    ON imoveis.bairro = bairros.cd_bairro
WHERE imoveis.cod = '1015' AND imoveis.status = '1' GROUP BY imoveis.id ORDER BY imoveis.id DESC
```

Comment: Como o Rafael Araújo indica deverá usar o LEFT JOIN. No stackoverflow existe muita informação sobre este tema.<br>
Exemplo.:<br>
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve usar `LEFT JOIN` para a tabelas de fotos.

```
SELECT imoveis.id, fotos.foto, imoveis.titulo, imoveis.descricao, imoveis.vvenda, imoveis.vtemporada, imoveis.vanual, imoveis.status, imoveis.cod
FROM
imoveis
INNER JOIN tipo
ON imoveis.tipo = tipo.cod
INNER JOIN bairros
ON imoveis.bairro = bairros.cd_bairro
LEFT JOIN fotos
ON imoveis.id = fotos.cod
WHERE imoveis.cod = '1015' AND imoveis.status = '1' GROUP BY imoveis.id ORDER BY imoveis.id DESC
```